# Creating Trees and Grass for unity ? How to add alpha layer to Vertex Colors?

Tags: unity

Ive been working for quite some time in small scene for unity, the scene is in a forest so there is plenty of trees and grass Im creating in Blender.. Im using the same technique in both cases, baking a high detail mesh into low poly planes and using these planes to populate the tree branches or making bushes of grass.

Everything is perfect, but Unity uses Alpha Vertex values to figure out how much those planes will swing with the wind, but Blender apparently doesnt have this feature!! So my tree branches planes and grass swing as a full object, I cant make the bottom vertex fixed because Unity considers they all have the same alpha value.

How can I work around this problem? Ive been looking in the internet for sometime and cant find a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the recent [nightly builds of blender](https://builder.blender.org/download/)

you can use the [Blender Vertex Color Master](https://github.com/andyp123/blender_vertex_color_master) Addon to get access to alpha channel.

From my quick experiments, the FBX exporter supports vertex colors. They show up in Unity. I couldn't text the animation because you didn't mention what shader you were using.

Comment: But the texture is not the problem, it is the verticies.

Unity uses the vertecies values to tell how much effect the Unity wind will have on those. It uses the Alpha value on each vertex to make this calculation.

So the problem is not the texture but the imput the mesh vertecies carry, and apparently Blender has no tool to allow us to edit the alpha value on the vertex

Comment: sorry, I mis-read. there is a 'bake to vertex color' option. I'll see if I can get that set up. Should be a similar process of baking the gradient to the vertices.

Comment: @Togu  I updated answer based on what you were asking. I think...